# vmware workstation Ubuntu 16.04 Guest to Windows 10 Host not pingable

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

As the title says I tried to connect my vm with Ubuntu 16.04 on it to my windows 10 machine in the first place but after hours of trying I don't know what is wrong. My ultimate goal is to connect from the Vm to another client in the network via ssh. My windows machine can connect without a problem to the client.

The network configuration for the client is the following:

ip 192.168.0.42  Subnetmask 255.255.255.0

for windows :

ip 192.168.0.50  Subnetmask 255.255.255.0

for the ubuntu vm:

ip 192.168.0.51  Subnetmask 255.255.255.0

Also for what I have tried so far:

1. Tried to change the vm setting to Bridged
   ->vm->settings->Adapter-> Bridge: connected directly to the physical network
2. Tried additionall to add the checkmark
3. Tried to change it to the custom VMnet0(Auto-bridging network)

Also I did read a few answers that seem to have fixed it for some others but these didn't help me either

I'm out of ideas right now and hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Follow the steps to set the ip for windows
2. Open VmWare
3. Select the wanted vm
4. Select vm ->Network Adapter -> Custom (VMnet0)
5. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation or the path where VMWare is installed
6. Open the vmnetcfg.exe
7. Click change Settings ( Needs admin privileges) !!
8. Select the earlier configurated network
9. Change the Vmnet Information  to the interface in my case :
   Intel(R) Ethernet Connection(2) I219-LM
10. Select applay and ok
11. Start the virtual machine

One problem was also that I'm simply not able to ping my pc because the firewall and security settings are set really high by the administration team .

I hope that I can help with my answer for others with a alike problem.